# How do I pass the result from httpget to SAX parser

Tags: saxparser, http-get, google-weather-api

I'm want to make a request to google API and pass the resulting XML to SAX parser here are both codes...

First the request:

```
HttpClient hclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Cardiff");

HttpResponse hrep = hclient.execute(get);
HttpEntity httpEntity = hrep.getEntity();
```

Then the parser:

```
SAXParserFactory saxpf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxp = saxpf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = saxp.getXMLReader();
ExHandler myHandler = new ExHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myHandler);
xr.parse();
```

Is this the right way to do this and how do I connect both codes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAXParser object can take in an input stream and the handler.  So something like:

```
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
saxParser.parse(httpEntity.getContent(),parser);
```

The getContent() method returns and input stream from the HttpRequest, and the XMLParser object is just a class I created (supposedly) that contains the definition of how to parse the XML.

**EDIT***
You really should read the entire API for SAXParser, it has several overloaded methods:

> void     parse(InputSource is, DefaultHandler dh)
>             Parse the content given InputSource as XML using the specified DefaultHandler.
>
> void     parse(InputSource is, HandlerBase hb)
>             Parse the content given InputSource as XML using the specified HandlerBase.
>
> void     **parse(InputStream is, DefaultHandler dh)**
>             Parse the content of the given InputStream instance as XML using the specified DefaultHandler.
>
> void  **parse(InputStream is, DefaultHandler dh, String systemId)**
>             Parse the content of the given InputStream instance as XML using the specified DefaultHandler.
>
> void  **parse(InputStream is, HandlerBase hb)**
>             Parse the content of the given InputStream instance as XML using the specified HandlerBase.
>
> void  **parse(InputStream is, HandlerBase hb, String systemId)**
>             Parse the content of the given InputStream instance as XML using the specified HandlerBase.

Some of the methods take an InputSource, some take an InputStream, as I stated earlier.

Comment: it's still not working, according to eclipse the parse method takes in an InputSource, is there a way to convert the httpEntity into an input source?

Comment: Basically, I just need to know how I can pass the response from the http request into the parser